# SpriteKit - How to stop a sound when enemy is killed

Tags: audio, sprite-kit

I'm building my first project with SpriteKit, but I can't figure out this part.

My project includes enemy helicopters flying into the screen. Each enemy plays a sound file around 14 seconds long. It's not a loop. It includes the sound of the enemy approaching before it enters the screen and more sound fx while it moves across the screen. The problem is that when I kill one of this helicopters, the sound keeps playing even after the enemy helicopter node has been removed from the scene.

I tried using the playSoundFileNamed action but I know those can't be stopped.

I tried using [SoundManager](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager) but since all the enemies have the same file id, if I stop one, it stops all of them, even the ones still on the screen.

I read I should use OpenAL but I can't find a source that explains how can I add some kind of ID to each sound playing to know which one to stop.

Same with AVAudioPlayer. I tried creating a player for each enemy but for some reason the runBlock SKAction just ignores this code and never plays the sound. Weird. I also read AVAudioPlayer is better for playing background music than with handling sound FX.

Is there some kind of sound engine that helps with this issue?

Comment: AVAudioPlayer works fine, use it.

Comment: I tried using AVAudioPlayer right now and was able to play a sound and even keep all the players (one for each enemy) in an array so I can pause them. The problem is that the sound still keeps playing when the enemy is removed from the scene. I tried removing all actions (which includes the AVAudioPlayer action) started by the node with removeAllActions when contact is detected but it still won't work. The sound keeps playing. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Post your code relevant to the sound issue. Your usage of AVAudioPlayer and keeping each instance in an array, all seem to be correct. So the problem must be in some part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it keeping all the audio players in an array. Here's the code:

First you create a NSMutableArray to keep track off all the players (called it 'playerArray'). Then each SKSpriteNode gets it's own player when they're added to the scene:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL * backgroundSound = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"coptersound" withExtension:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *copterPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundSound error:&error];
copterPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;
copterPlayer.delegate = self;
[copterPlayer prepareToPlay];

SKAction *moveCopter = [SKAction moveToX:(-10 - enemy.size.width) duration:14];
SKAction *copterSound = [SKAction runBlock:^{

    [playerArray addObject:copterPlayer];
    [copterPlayer play];

    [enemy.userData setValue:copterPlayer forKeyPath:@"player"];

}];

SKAction *moveGroup = [SKAction group:@[copterSound, moveCopter]];
```

Then when collision is detected, this is how I stop the player:

```
   [[enemy.userData objectForKey:@"player"] stop];
   [playerArray removeObject:[enemy.userData objectForKey:@"player"]];
```

Need to pause all the players? Do this:

```
    for(AVAudioPlayer *a in playerArray) {
        [a pause];
    }
```

And don't forget to remove all the players that have finished playing from the array using this:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    [playerArray removeObject:player];
}
```

Not sure if it's the best way but it works perfectly. Still open for better suggestions since it's my first time working with SpriteKit.

Answer (score 0):

playSoundWithFile can be stopped,  add a child SKNode to your helicopter,  play the sound on your child, then just pause the child